# How to fix docker daemon that will not restart due to hns error

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, windows-server, docker-for-windows

- Docker for Windows Server
- Windows Server version 1709, with containers
- Docker version 17.06.2-ee-6, build e75fdb8
- Swarm mode (worker node, part of swarm with ubuntu masters)

After containers connected to an overlay network started intermittently losing their network adapters, I restarted the machine.  Now daemon will not start.  Below is the last lines of output from running docker -D.

Please let me know how to fix this.

```
time="2018-05-15T15:10:06.731160000Z" level=debug msg="Option Experimental: false"
time="2018-05-15T15:10:06.731160000Z" level=debug msg="Option DefaultDriver: nat"
time="2018-05-15T15:10:06.731160000Z" level=debug msg="Option DefaultNetwork: nat"
time="2018-05-15T15:10:06.734183700Z" level=info msg="Restoring existing overlay networks from HNS into docker"
time="2018-05-15T15:10:06.735174400Z" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/] Request : "
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.789120400Z" level=debug msg="Network (d4d37ce) restored"
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.796122200Z" level=debug msg="Endpoint (4114b6e) restored to network (d4d37ce)"
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.796122200Z" level=debug msg="Endpoint (819eb70) restored to network (d4d37ce)"
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.797124900Z" level=debug msg="Endpoint (ade55ea) restored to network (d4d37ce)"
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.798125600Z" level=debug msg="Endpoint (d0054fc) restored to network (d4d37ce)"
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.798125600Z" level=debug msg="Endpoint (e2af8d8) restored to network (d4d37ce)"
time="2018-05-15T15:12:06.854118500Z" level=debug msg="[GET]=>[/networks/] Request : "
time="2018-05-15T15:14:06.860654000Z" level=debug msg="start clean shutdown of all containers with a 15 seconds timeout..."
Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: hnsCall failed in Win32: Server execution failed (0x80080005)
```

Comment: 1. Update to ee-10, ee-6 has some vulnerabilities
2. Try Get-ContainerNetwork | remove-containernetwork

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete set of steps to completely rebuild all docker issues withing swarm host. Sometimes only some steps are sufficient (specifically hns part), so you can try those first.

```
Remove all docker services and user-defined networks (so all docker networks except `nat` and `none`
Leave the swarm cluster (docker swarm leave --force)
Stop the docker service (PS C:\> stop-service docker)
Stop the HNS service (PS C:\> stop-service hns)
In regedit, delete all of the registry keys under these paths:
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\parameters\SwitchList
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\vmsmp\parameters\NicList
Now go to Device Manager, and disable then remove all network adapters that are “Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet…” adapters
Now rename your HNS.data file (the goal is to effectively “delete” it by renaming it):
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\HNS\HNS.data
Also rename C:\ProgramData\docker folder (the goal is to effectively “delete” it by renaming it)
C:\ProgramData\docker

Now reboot your machine
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this info, Gregory.   But this is too much.  Especially on gui-less windows server with powershell only.  Easier to just deallocate machine and start over with new server, using azure template 'Windows Server version 1709, with containers'.   Hopefully server 1803 or 2019 will be better. :|

Comment: True but I had to perform operation above more then once on docker swarm. Waiting for AKS to go live with windows containers to stop this mayhem